# Is it possible to track all methods called on an object?

Tags: objective-c

I'm still working on my problem that an NSView in NSMenuItem is not receiving any notification when the user chooses it by pressing the return key.

For this i want to log all methods which are called on an Objective-C object.
Can i do this in some way without using a debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily, no, and probably not the most effective way to debug this anyway.   If it isn't receiving a notification, it is likely that no method is being called.

You could build a proxy class that forwards all methods and then plug that in, logging as it forwards.  See the documentation for NSProxy for more information.

But, again, not the best way to debug this.

Do you have a separate question regarding the views, menus, and notifications? (I didn't obviously find one).

Comment: He did, but he deleted it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429749/cocoa-custom-nsview-in-nsmenuitem-does-not-repsonse-to-enter-key